Can compiler optimizations avoid writing to memory by operating exclusively in registers?
Context:
In multithreaded programming, one of the key challenges is ensuring that changes made by one thread are visible to others. While this issue is commonly tied to memory visibility, another potential factor is how compilers handle register caching for variables that are not explicitly marked as shared (e.g., without volatile or synchronization mechanisms).
Consider the following Java example:
public class Example {
    static boolean run = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            run = false;  // Producer updates the value
        }).start();

        while (run) {
            // Consumer waits for the update
        }
        System.out.println("Exited loop.");
    }
}

Here, the variable run is used to coordinate between two threads. Since it is not marked volatile or synchronized, a compiler might assume that the variable is thread-local. This raises an interesting question:
Could the compiler optimize access to run by caching it in a CPU register, avoiding writes to memory? If so, this would:

Prevent the cache-coherency mechanisms from triggering, as registers are core-local.
Result in the consumer thread never seeing the updated value, causing an infinite loop.

This scenario might adhere to program logic, but it could break the memory visibility guarantees expected in multithreaded environments.

The Question:
Is it possible, in practice, for modern compilers to optimize variable access such that the value is held exclusively in registers, bypassing memory writes entirely?

If so, what are the circumstances that allow such behavior?
How do modern memory models (e.g., JVM, x86) and compiler standards mitigate or prevent this scenario?


Goal:
The objective is to understand:

Whether such optimizations are feasible in real-world systems.
The mechanisms (if any) in compilers and architectures that ensure memory visibility in such cases.


not java-specific but you have a finite number of registers, so any compiler needs to write the data to the memory eventually so it can free the registers. but temporary changes can be done in registers (like temporarily setting run to false then true, or even not stored at all due to optimizations), but even for an imaginary computer that doesn't have registers, temporary changes have no guarantee of being visible by other cores due to store buffers.

@AhmedAEK But a commit will still happen from the store buffer, right? Entries definitely won’t be delayed there, as it gets drained as quickly as practically possible. Overall, I’m satisfied with the understanding that values can be held in registers. I just thought there might be operations that require mandatory interaction with memory, which would imply the need to drop down to a level below registers.

@AhmedAEK Yes, because there is no volatile. But as far as I understand, this will happen precisely if the value false assigned to the variable run remains in one of the registers and is not associated back with the memory address.

just an fyi, your code has undefined behavior in C/C++/rust and you may have an infinite loop because although they do guarantee that the worker thread does the write to the main memory, those languages memory model doesn't guarantee that run will be re-read from the main memory every loop iteration (because it is not atomic), the language memory model is the only guarantee you have. and the language tries to fulfil those guarantees by adding whatever instructions are necessary to ensure those guarantees hold on all hardware, relying on the hardware instead of the language is wrong.

It's not volatile so Java is allowed to hoist the load out of the loop, turning it into if(!run) while(true){}.  Same as C and C++, except that in those languages the data race is UB.  Java doesn't have UB; if a load sees a value, it won't be torn for narrow-enough types.  But there isn't a guarantee of that for plain vars without synchronization.  See MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop / Multithreading program stuck in optimized mode but runs normally in -O0

Background info: Java Memory Model on Wikipedia.

in Java this can also be an infinite loop ( @Ahmed )

@AhmedAEK I understand, as sequential consistency is not guaranteed for multithreaded execution without the use of synchronization mechanisms. Writing to main memory (cache and/or RAM) would be strictly necessary to ensure consistency in multithreaded execution. However, if we haven't established a synchronization order, the compiler can afford more liberties in terms of its behavior strategy and the use of registers for optimization. Am I understanding this correctly?

@AhmedAEK  Also, nothing prevents the use of registers for intermediate computations; it's just that a commit would be required if synchronization is present.

yes, and a thread starting or terminating is a synchronization point, therefore the compiler needs to commit all the work the thread has done to the main memory at some point, but at any point before that you have no guarantees unless you add your own synchronization, on the other hand, joining a thread is also a synchronization point, so you are also guaranteed to see the work the thread has done if you join it. but if you don't join it then you need to add your own synchronization. and the above code doesn't join the thread so it is not guaranteed to see the work the thread has done.

@PeterCordes This is very interesting! Is such unusual behavior theoretically allowed? I assumed there were guarantees regarding reordering and optimizations, ensuring that in the presence of a loop, instructions that are part of its body would not be moved outside the control structure. Although, interestingly, this wouldn't contradict the semantics of the program in single-threaded execution, it causes serious issues in multithreaded environments without synchronization.

@AhmedAEK I understand. Simply put, in the absence of synchronization, there are no ironclad guarantees that a commit to main memory will even occur. And if it does happen eventually, we won’t know when, and in theory, this moment could be significantly delayed. At that point, everything will depend on how the compiler operates. In general, registers are used regularly, but to avoid problems with holding values in them, synchronization must be properly managed.

@AhmedAEK I just wanted to confirm that this is indeed possible and could be one of the sources of visibility issues when synchronization is mishandled.

@BasilBourque Thank you, this is a key source! And what is very important is the fact that the JMM itself does not contradict such behavior. Holding a value in registers would be possible and would not violate anything in terms of memory consistency, as long as we do not guarantee synchronized order using synchronization mechanisms. Sequential consistency "out of the box," relying on the JMM, is only available for single-threaded execution.

@user85421 Let me clarify. As I understand it, the infinite loop here would have two sources: the retention of the value in a register and the potential for reordering at the compiler level, where the check could be moved outside the loop, as noted by the respected Peter Cordes. That’s how I understand it, at least.

How is that "unusual"?  We want loads hoisted and stores sunk out of loops for non-shared variables, and they were allowed in C and C++ before they had a thread-aware memory model.  Data races being UB is what still allows that.  (In more realistic cases where the optimization is useful for single-threaded code, there's some work inside the loop, but no opaque function calls to functions that might have a reference to the variable being optimized into a register.)

@PeterCordes In short, if a variable is not explicitly designated as shared in terms of applying synchronization mechanisms to it, this fact alone opens up a wide range of possible optimizations that the compiler may potentially apply if it deems them beneficial. Calling it "unusual" wasn’t entirely correct, indeed. It was unusual to me personally, but that’s subjective. Things become much clearer when everything falls into place!

[what] compiler standards mitigate or prevent this - Languages provide things like Java volatile, C++ std::atomic, C# VolatileRead, etc. which forbid this, allowing you to write spin-wait loops on shared variables.  If you don't use those language features, the resulting broken code is the programmer's fault.  And compilers have to account for the possibility that an acquire (or stronger) load synchronized with a writer, so non-atomic variables now have new values and have to be re-read.  From your last comment, yeah seems like you're getting it.

@PeterCordes I envisioned this a bit differently. Essentially, if we consider a scenario where our code completely lacks any synchronization mechanisms, then even with multiple threads (strictly more than one), any compiler (whether it's a bytecode compiler or a compiler within the JVM) will treat each thread as a self-contained thread. In theory, such a thread safely exists on its own and doesn't intersect with any other thread of execution.

@PeterCordes Even if this isn't the case in reality, compilers will axiomatically perceive the situation this way because they have no knowledge of our intentions. After all, perhaps this behavior is precisely what we want for some specific testing purposes. No compiler or even AI will ever be able to read the programmer's mind to confirm this.

@PeterCordes Therefore, the compiler's task is to ensure program order, specifically from the perspective of observable changes. This means that as-if-serial ordering is permissible, which might either match the actual program order or differ from it, but it will always appear consistent from the perspective of observable behavior.

@PeterCordes Clearly, based on this logic, the compiler can effectively perform any reordering as long as it doesn't violate program order, at least in the context of as-if-serial. Consequently, thinking within the paradigm of self-contained threads seems to fit quite elegantly here, as I see it.

Yes, in C++ without atomic or volatile variables or sync ops like mutex lock/unlock, any program transformation is allowed as long as it doesn't break single-threaded code.  (Except for inventing writes to objects this thread doesn't even read.  The asm equivalents of if(cond) x = 1; and x = cond ? 1 : x; differ if another thread is also writing x.  Even on machines where data races in asm don't do anything weird, it could still overwrite a change made by another thread.) https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/ lists a lot of interesting stuff compilers can do.

i.e. the as-if rule only requires compilers to preserve a limited set of things that count as observable, including I/O and volatile accesses.  And in practice, without whole-program optimization, not changing struct layouts and stuff that might be visible across ABI boundaries, especially in function calls to/from code the optimizer can't see.  And within a single thread, without the optimizer changing how threads communicate with each other (which no compilers do in practice), some visibility requirements around atomic ops (and ordering if not relaxed).

@PeterCordes In theory, the compiler can indeed perform what might seem like "radical" transformations, as I understand it. If a certain effect is not considered observable from the compiler's perspective, and we are working within the context of a self-contained thread (at least as the compiler would assume due to the absence of synchronization mechanisms), the compiler could optimize the code to the extent of eliminating all reads and writes if they are unrelated to I/O operations or their results are not tied to function calls.

@PeterCordes Why not, in principle? It may seem extreme to some, but at the same time, it fully aligns with the "as-if-serial" rule.

Compilers do perform such optimizations in practice.  e.g. clang can optimize away everything from a function that creates and destroys a std::vector and fills it with values.  https://godbolt.org/z/GKKn36rve

@PeterCordes Indeed, nothing remains except for the return. I’m not sure if Java compilers can theoretically do the same, but on the other hand, I understand that there’s nothing stopping them from replicating this behavior if we think about it. Quite the opposite, the more a compiler can potentially remove without breaking any rules, the higher the likelihood it will do so. At least, this seems logical to me, although I understand that everything depends on the specific implementation of the compiler and the algorithms it operates on.

@DmytroKostenko the whole function can be removed. First of all it could be inlined, but if the JIT sees that a function doesn't have any effect, it could completely get rid of the whole thing. You are making the JMM a lot more complicated than needed (and it can already be completed enough). Function calls are not part of the JMM, it care about reads, writes, synchronization actions etc. If you want to understand the JMM, ignore everything else you know.

@DmytroKostenko Just assume that the JIT can do whatever it wants, as long as it doesn't violate the 'within-threads as-if-serial' semantics unless there is some form of synchronization. It can even get rid of synchronization actions if it can prove that they have no effect.

@DmytroKostenko a memory model effectively is the set of all allowed executions and the only thing the JVM needs to take care of is to generate executions that can be justified by an execution in the memory model. So for every real execution, there needs to be a justifying execution in the memory model for the JVM to be a legal implementation of the JMM. As long as the above holds, the JVM can optimize the hell out of code.

@pveentjer
Exactly, I’m also starting to think that the JIT can do absolutely anything as long as it doesn’t violate the within-thread “as-if-serial” semantics, and this helps to understand everything else. I knew about inlining, but for some reason, I didn’t recall it in the context of this discussion. And indeed, there are even special JVM flags that allow controlling this process. For some reason, I thought that a function call was something mandatory. Like, shouldn’t the program at least do something in the end?

@pveentjer Now I realize that even a large program, if it doesn’t produce anything useful and instead does something meaningless, can be optimized down to “nothingness.” In general, there’s no point in questioning what the compiler can or cannot do. It’s easier to assume that, by default, it can do absolutely anything, but the only restriction here is the memory model, which it is obliged not to violate. As long as it doesn’t violate it and the observable logic is preserved, you’re absolutely right about any optimization behavior.

@pveentjer If a large program is structured so that it produces no observable effects at all, and there’s no synchronization, then in the end, we might indeed end up with nothing. At least in theory... And I think it’s quite possible in practice as well.


In multithreaded programming, one of the key challenges is ensuring that changes made by one thread are visible to others. While this issue is commonly tied to memory visibility, another potential factor is how compilers handle register caching for variables that are not explicitly marked as shared (e.g., without volatile or synchronization mechanisms).

I think you are misunderstanding what it means to be a memory model. The memory model is concerned with reading from and writing to memory, and what memory is is defined from the context of the system that memory model works on. From the JVM perspective, any field read/write is a memory access. The compiler, therefore, must adhere to the memory model, and produces a valid mapping between the reads/writes in the source machine (the JVM abstract machine) to the reads/writes in the destination machine (the x86 machine for example). This means run = false and while (run) are memory accesses and they must adhere to the rules of the JVM memory model. The compiler can then from this memory model chooses not to materialize all of them, but this is a consequence of adhering to the memory model, not a factor you have to think about when reasoning about the memory model.

Here, the variable run is used to coordinate between two threads. Since it is not marked volatile or synchronized, a compiler might assume that the variable is thread-local.

This is incorrect, the compiler cannot assume that the variable is thread-local, as its accesses can be coordinated upon using other synchronisation devices. For example, the termination of a thread happens before the return of any join method on that thread object. And it is perfectly race-free for the consumer to join with the producer before reading run, and it would be incorrect for the compiler to elide the write in that case. As a result, I can be almost certain saying that the compiler cannot elide the write to run.

I understand the main idea, although I must admit that while formulating my question, I allowed myself to make some rather rough inaccuracies. So, I just want to summarize to ensure I have correctly understood your point. You are suggesting that compilers, which rely on a given high-level programming language, can and most likely will apply optimizations—at the very least, they will not avoid them. These optimizations might include instruction reordering and active use of registers wherever possible.

The key point is that such optimizations must not contradict the existing memory model specified for the programming language. For example, if we are discussing the operation of a particular JIT compiler, its behavior must comply with the Java Memory Model (JMM). Nevertheless, returning to the essence of the question, I conclude that this is possible, as there are no contradictions with the JMM in this case.

Yes, on the one hand, I mistakenly referred to thread-locality, but if the program code truly lacks any synchronization mechanisms, this opens up the possibility for careful yet valid optimizations in this scenario. If the compiler detects that we are actively working with a variable and, for instance, frequently changing its value—say, inside a loop—it could, in theory, choose not to write the value to cache or main memory each time but instead operate directly with registers. From a semantic perspective, this does not violate any rules.

Moreover, if the code lacks any synchronization mechanisms, the compiler might, by default, interpret this as single-threaded execution.

Since the 'run' variable isn't volatile (and there are no other forms of synchronization), the load of the 'run' can be hoisted out of the loop. So if you claim this can't happen, then your answer is not correct. Accordign to the JMM, only when a program is free of data races, then only sequential consistent executions are allowed. And there is a clear data race on the 'run' variable, so non-sequential consistent executions are allowed.  And lack of visibility is perfectly legal.

@pveentjer Are there any more formalized rules regarding reorderings related to loops? Or is it much simpler, and should we approach this from the opposite perspective? Let me clarify what I mean.
If a given reordering or optimization (even to the extent that a certain instruction may be entirely removed by the compiler) does not contradict the existing memory model of the programming language, then it can potentially be left to the discretion of the compiler. All the specific implementation details of such optimizations depend on the internal algorithms of the compiler itself.

@pveentjer It is a different matter when we establish a synchronization order using available synchronization mechanisms. The responsibility for adhering to that order also lies with the compiler, and there can be various approaches to achieving this. However, the compiler is required to generate code that, at the point of synchronization, completely eliminates any possibility of a data race. One of the hallmarks of such an order is the absence of the mentioned data race condition.

@pveentjer If no special rules exist on this matter apart from the memory model itself, it would simplify the understanding of these concepts.

@pveentjer What I said is that in the practical sense the write to run cannot be elided because the compiler cannot easily say that the write is redundant.

@DmytroKostenko : use a simple approach. If there are no data races, ordering, visibility, and atomicity are guaranteed. But if there is a data race (due to lack of volatile in this case) these properties do not need to be provided. Although Java isn't allowed to have the same level of undefined behavior as C++. In your example, due to the data race, visibility can be sacrificed, by hoisting the read out of the loop (see the transformation Peter Cordess posted in your opening question). PS: data race != race condition. And data race condition doesn't exist.

@DmytroKostenko in very simple terms: if there is a data race (nearly) anything is allowed. So you don't need to remember any special rules about loops or other statements.

@QuânAnhMai Yes, for that, it would be necessary to know the entire context, which is inherently excessive and could negatively impact performance. Nevertheless, it seems possible, at least from the perspective that it does not violate the existing rules of the memory model. Here, much depends on the compiler itself and, I believe, cannot be excluded, on the options with which it was launched.

@pveentjer I envisioned it somewhat similarly. Potentially, everything is possible except for the reordering of operations that affect the same memory address, but that makes sense, as it would alter the observable program order. Essentially, the possibility of optimizations, as I understand it, relies on observable effects—effects that could be observed by some external "observer" (whether it’s another thread, if inter-thread interaction is assumed, or the programmer directly, when it comes to ensuring the correct logic of the program as defined in program order).

@pveentjer So, it’s not out of the question that the code of some method could be "optimized" to the extent that there’s absolutely nothing left of it—literally nothing. I also started thinking about the factors a compiler would rely on in such cases. I believe that side effects, if they are expected, also play a crucial role here. If a particular operation can produce an observable side effect, the compiler won’t bother figuring out why we need it; it will assume that it was intended.

@pveentjer Removing such an operation would not be permissible because it would affect consistency in terms of program order guarantees, which must hold within the context of a single thread when considered in an isolated environment.

@DmytroKostenko that is incorrect. There is a data race, so ordering, visibility and atomicity are not guaranteed. And for the thread that does the loop, it doesn't matter if the load gets hoisted ouf of the loop; the effects are the same. So the 'within-thread as-if-serial' semantics are preserved.

If program order should always be preserved, then nearly all compiler optimizations would be forbidden. Also, memory fences would be needed after every load/store to prevent the CPU from reordering them even if the fields are not accessed concurrently.

If the 'run' variable would be made volatile, the data race disappears. And as a consequence, hoisting the 'run' variable out of the loop would be forbidden since it would violate visibility (and potentially ordering if other variables are involved).

@DmytroKostenko: "Potentially, everything is possible except for the reordering of operations that affect the same memory address". Even that isn't guaranteed. So coherence (the memory model for a single address), which effectively is sequential consistency per address,  isn't guaranteed with plain loads and stores. https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/basic/BasicJMM_05_Coherence.java

@pveentjer It turns out I was a bit too hasty regarding the same memory address. In principle, if the compiler can perform certain reorderings or other optimizations—regardless of their nature—provided these reorderings do not affect the "observable" order of program execution, and thus the program executes at least according to the as-if-serial principle, then such reorderings are permitted. Clearly, these operations do not require additional synchronization, and this behavior is always present.

@pveentjer We cannot guarantee absolute data consistency between threads that interact by reading from and writing to the same regions of shared memory unless we eliminate all data races that could potentially be observed in the code. When I talk about guarantees, I mean guarantees in the context of program instructions being executed within the confines of each individual thread, assuming they are all considered in isolation from each other.

@pveentjer The actual execution order of the program at runtime is unlikely to be fully known, even with a disassembler in hand, due to CPU-level reorderings. However, we do know that the actual execution order could precisely match the program order, or more likely, it will follow the as-if-serial order. This includes instruction reordering and/or other various optimizations in the code, which no longer strictly adhere to the program order in terms of existing instructions but still conform to it in terms of logic and observable behavior.

@DmytroKostenko The reordering of instructions can't be observed within the thread (within-thread as-if-serial semantics), but it certainly can be observed by other threads.

@pveentjer Yes, yes, that's exactly what I meant. The as-if-serial semantics provide guarantees of sequential execution of instructions in terms of the program's logical flow. But this does not mean that the actual order will be the same if reorderings are applied or if certain sections of code are entirely omitted. Nevertheless, this does not affect the logic and flow of program execution, which is also built on this logic, and all observable effects will correspond to what would occur under strict program order.

@pveentjer This is undoubtedly important for inter-thread interactions as well, but it does not guarantee consistency if a data race is potentially possible and proper synchronization is absent. Overall, this is how I understand it, and it seems that the foundation is correctly established. Perhaps there are issues in understanding certain details, but this should be refined over time.

@DmytroKostenko "Nevertheless, this does not affect the logic and flow of program execution, which is also built on this logic, and all observable effects will correspond to what would occur under strict program order.". This is incorrect. If there is a data race, reordering, visibility and atomicity problems can become visible.

@DmytroKostenko I have spend enough time answering questions and have the impression that no further progress is made. I would suggest reading the JMM and get a very solid understanding of sequential consistency before asking more questions on SO.

@pveentjer Yes, you’re right. Thank you so much for the conversation! You know, I’ve gained a lot of useful insights anyway. I’ll keep diving deeper into this topic!

In general? Absolutely. That's the whole reason for the register keyword in C/C++, and even more pointedly the deprecation of the register keyword -- modern compilers will aggressively use registers instead of memory (and stack, for function calls) when possible, especially in x64 where there are a lot of registers to use.
In Java specifically? I doubt it. Keep in mind that the JVM interprets most of the code, it doesn't even generate native assembly code from it.

Well, the JVM can be forced to work in pure compiler mode using the appropriate flags, which is no secret. I just assume that if this were the case, the described issues of variable visibility wouldn't exist. Or do they have a completely different nature? At the moment, I don't see many other ways to reproduce a situation where changes fail to propagate between threads on different cores indefinitely.

As for C and C++, I know the compiler could be "advised" to do such things. This is an excellent example, in my opinion! But with the JVM, it's not so straightforward. It's one thing when we're dealing with local variables, but when we change the value of a field located in the dynamic heap, i.e., in shared memory, do we really have the right not to write the result to memory and instead continue holding it in one of the registers?

Was that why you were asking? Cause there's countless ways you get race conditions between threads using the same memory locations. You either write correct multi-threaded code, using correct memory barriers and interlocked/volatile reads (very difficult), or you don't share memory between threads, and use threads to run tasks and return new objects instead.

"As for C and C++, I know the compiler could be "advised" to do such things" -- that wasn't my point, my point is that it will always aggressively use registers instead of stack/memory when it can. And that's not just C and C++, but everything that transpiles to it, like Python, Rust, Javascript, Ruby I think? This is just how modern software works.

No, I was more interested in low-level mechanisms in the context of visibility. Why might it happen that changes made by one thread are not visible to another thread for an indefinite amount of time? I’ve concluded that at the processor level, this can only occur due to values being held in registers, since attempting to write to memory would trigger the cache-coherency protocol. I just wanted to confirm that a compiler could take such an approach. I was trying to understand the nature of this phenomenon.

So, am I correct in understanding that wherever possible, we will indeed keep values in registers, potentially "bypassing" and avoiding a commit to cache memory/RAM? At the same time, if we use synchronization, the strategy obviously changes fundamentally. Am I getting this right?

Yes, but again most likely not in JVM. But again that's just one case, another much more common root cause of these issues is that even if it's not held by registers, it can be held by any of the 3 levels of CPU caches per core, and it can hold more or less even within a thread as it moves tasks around. It's important to note that different cores have different caches.

This answer seems correct in everything except the treatment of the JVM, which certainly will make optimizations like this in hot paths in the code.

Yea.  The last sentence of the Answer ("the JVM interprets most of the code, it doesn't even generate native assembly code from it.") is blatantly wrong.  Some JVMs (e.g. GraalVM) can use an AOT native code compiler.  And for a HotSpot JVM, any "hot" code will be JIT compiled to native code, given time.  (Unless you deliberately disable the JIT compiler.)

Besides the HotSpot JIT compiler, we also have the OpenJ9 JIT compiler in some JDK products.

"I’ve concluded that at the processor level, this can only occur due to values being held in registers, since attempting to write to memory would trigger the cache-coherency protocol." This is incorrect, the thing that works in an unintuitive manner here is the load in the consumer, which is hoisted out of the loop. As a result, the consumer never observes the change in the value of run because it never attempts to do so.

@Blindy The situation with caches is more or less acceptable. There are certainly nuances, but all modern processors are equipped with hardware cache-coherency protocols that ensure consistency, including at the level of local cache memory for all cores relative to one another. To definitively confirm that registers can be a source of such issues, it seems necessary to verify this through a disassembled listing. However, if C-like languages operate this way, then what’s the issue with Java compilers?

@LouisWasserman I agree, especially considering that there are many ways to attempt to control this process by using the appropriate VM options passed to the JVM at launch. For example, the -Xcomp flag, which immediately compiles all code into machine instructions. Therefore, some parallels with C/C++ can indeed be drawn.

@StephenC You could also mention the integration with C/C++ code via JNI, which may include assembly inserts, though I’m not sure how relevant that would be in this context. When discussing compilation/interpretation modes, there are certainly ways to force the JVM to fully compile the code. However, whether this is necessary or effective depends on Java's capabilities and use cases.

@BasilBourque Are you referring to OpenJ9 in the context of AOT compilation?

@QuânAnhMai I understand. This is yet another reason (possibly even the main one) that can lead to the consumer never seeing the result of the write. However, this is only possible due to code optimization as part of reordering, where, as you correctly noted, the check is performed just once and moved outside the loop. Previously, I wondered whether such a reordering was possible, as I assumed that operations could not be moved out of a loop. But now I realize that such restrictions do not always apply and are not enforced for all code. Synchronization must be used to prevent such reordering.

@DmytroKostenko No, I said the OpenJ9 JIT compiler, an alternative to HotSpot. (In addition to the JIT compiler, OpenJ9 also offers an Ahead of Time (AOT) compilation feature.)

@BasilBourque Oh, now I understand you! Thank you for the clarification! It seems that they also started implementing AOT in HotSpot, but as far as I remember, the AOT compilation mechanism is still considered an experimental feature.

@DmytroKostenko I do not know of any AOT features in HotSpot. You may be thinking of future features being considered under Project Leyden. And there is the alternative to both HotSpot & OpenJ9, GraalVM which does offer AOT native compilation.

@BasilBourque Yes, you are probably right, and that’s exactly what I meant. I remember that such initiatives appeared quite some time ago but existed at an experimental level starting with Java 9. At that point, AOT compilation could be tested using the jaotc utility. Later, all these initiatives were redirected to GraalVM, if I’m not mistaken.

You don't need anything but absolutely vanilla HotSpot with no flags to get these sorts of optimizations.

@LouisWasserman Overall, this is certainly possible. I think the discussion was more about how various flags allow for finer control over the optimization process, enabling some things to be restricted while making others more aggressive. However, I agree that the compiler can work to its full potential even without any specific settings, as this is the main idea—to apply all necessary optimizations wherever it is feasible.
